# debugging htaccess rewrite that isn't working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess file, which should rewrite all non-existent files/folder to index.php. Could someone suggest a way to debug why this wouldn't work? When I go to a non-existent folder I receive a 404 not-found page.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

when I visit `domain.com/` the index.php file shows properly

the .htaccess file is in the same directory as index.php

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must ensure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled and working, otherwise you will keep getting `500 Internal Server Error`.

You can check that, simply by using `apache_get_modules()`. For example,

```
// File : test.php
<?php

if (in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules()){
   echo 'mod_rewrite is installed and ready to be used';
} else {
   echo 'mod_rewrite is not installed';
}
```

If it prints that `mod_rewrite is installed and ready to be used`, then you can use something like this,

```
    RewriteEngine On

    # I guess you're missing RewriteBase
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Is this placed in DOCUMENT_ROOT with mod_rewrite and .htaccess enabled?

Comment: I'll check, it's a brand new server so could be the culprit

Comment: did you try to remove `.` so `/index.php`

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy: Thanks yes that was a typo.

Comment: that is really strange. Is .htaccess even enabled? Can you put some garbage text on top of this file and see if it generates 500 error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
```

EDIT
here is post you may be useful [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules?rq=1)

Comment: Unfortunately, still doesn't work. Maybe my issue is larger than the .htaccess file's content

Comment: firstly need to make sure that htaccess is enabled